# How to check if website is listed in DMOZ from Python?

Tags: python, django

I need to check if website is listed in DMOZ using Python script. How can I do it? I'm trying to do it like this:

```
import urllib2
search = "http://www.dmoz.org/search?q="
domain = "example.com"
r = urllib2.urlopen(search+domain).read()
```

It returns html code. I don't understand what should I search in that html code to check if website is listed in DMOZ. Please help me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you look inside returned HTML you will see `<!---------- SITES RESULTS ---------->` comment with `<section class="results sites">` section. Inside this section you will find `<div class="site-item">`. Several `<div>` deeper you can see what you are looking for:

```
<div class="site-url">
...
</div>
```

Site itself and it's sub-domains listed there.

If your site is not in catalog there will be no `<div class="site-item">`. Search for it in your Python script.